# How i remove the corresponding index in the label column?

Tags: pandas, series

I have a Dataset of News

After the cleaning stage, I noticed that 3 news becomes empty and I deleted them
But I want to delete the corresponding index within the label column (Series pandas) so that the two Series's (cleaned & label) becomes equal so that no problems grow when dividing in the training stage for classification such this error

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [997, 1000]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). It will solve the problem.

`df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to first perform feature engineering(if necessary) and cleaning your data. Then split your data into X_train (dataframe with features) and y_train(target feature).

That way you find such issues.